# Testing statusOK via Selenium IDE

Tags: if-statement, selenium-ide

After reading a couple of articles online, I am trying to get this to work, but failed...can someone advise?

**Platform**: Selenium IDE 3.17.0 (Chrome)

**Command**: If

**Target**: ${!statusOK}

I am getting this error: Unexpected token '{'

I tried to remove the $ sign and the squiggly brackets, but no luck....